# how to declare variables in class?

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
class one
{
public:
  typedef int (*funPtr) (void);
  one()
  {
    // here I'm using map variable which is private. 
  }
  ~one(){}

private:
  typedef map<int, funPtr> mMap;
  mMap mapVar;  
};
```

In this case class constructor gives that error that map is not declared. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Judging by the comments we seem to all have different opinions on what you're TRYING to accomplish, could you perhaps show the constructor code?

Comment: @Ben - no offense, but when he says "here I'm using map variable which is private" when he doesn't *have* a private variable, and says the error is " that map is not declared" ... He doesn't understand what `typedef` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typedef defines a type...basically an aliasing...if you wish to declare a variable mMap of type map you would just do

```
map mMap;
```

Comment: Or since you seem to have edited your code since then, map<int, funPtr> mMap;

Comment: +1 - but may be worth mentioning #include <map> and the std namespace.

Answer (score 1):

For the compiler to know what map is, the typedef for map should be placed before first usage.

Comment: This wouldn't solve his problem. He hasn't *declared* a variable anywhere

Comment: +1 that comment - or if he has, it's a local variable in the constructor (and not shown), not a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're not declaring a variable anywhere.

You would need to *use* the typedef to declare an actual variable:

```
typedef map<int, funPtr> mMap;
mMap myMap;
```

I suspect you're not meaning to use `typedef` at all, and simply need to be doing:

```
map<int, funPtr> mMap;
```

Comment: +1 simply put and well said. The suspicion seems very likely. m pre-pended to mMap does suggest a member varible being created.